# Can i recompile kernel in dualboot environment?

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, compiling, patch

I need to fix a value hid-ids.h and compile kernel so that my device will work. But i'm on dualboot with windows 8. If this goes wrong can it damage grub or will this just affect my ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't affect GRUB, only your kernel.

Worst case, Windows should still boot, Ubuntu wouldn't with your new kernel.

Generally, you should still be able to get back into Ubuntu by using the older kernel, so it really shouldn't affect Ubuntu that much either.

Comment: thanks, compiling it rigt now... I have also one additional question. Can i make modified hid-ids.h as a kernel patch and apply it to kernel?